# Spring/Rest @PathVariable character encoding

Tags: spring, rest, character-encoding, uri

In the environment I'm using (Tomcat 6), percent sequences in path segments apparently are decoded using ISO-8859-1 when being mapped to a @PathVariable.

I'd like that to be UTF-8.

I already configured Tomcat to use UTF-8 (using the URIEncoding attribute in server.xml).

Is Spring/Rest doing the decoding on its own? If yes, where can I override the default encoding?

Additional information; here's my test code:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/enc/{foo}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public HttpEntity<String> enc( @PathVariable( "foo" ) String foo, HttpServletRequest req )
{
  String resp;

  resp = "      path variable foo: " + foo + "\n" + 
         "      req.getPathInfo(): " + req.getPathInfo() + "\n" +
         "req.getPathTranslated(): " + req.getPathTranslated() + "\n" + 
         "    req.getRequestURI(): " + req.getRequestURI() + "\n" + 
         "   req.getContextPath(): " + req.getContextPath() + "\n";

  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setContentType( new MediaType( "text", "plain", Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ) ) );
  return new HttpEntity<String>( resp, headers );
}
```

If I do an HTTP GET request with the following URI path:

```
/TEST/enc/%c2%a3%20and%20%e2%82%ac%20rates
```

which is the UTF-8 encoded then percent-encoded form of

```
/TEST/enc/£ and € rates
```

the output that I get is:

```
      path variable foo: Â£ and â¬ rates
      req.getPathInfo(): /enc/£ and € rates
req.getPathTranslated(): C:\Users\jre\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\TEST\enc\£ and € rates
    req.getRequestURI(): /TEST/enc/%C2%A3%20and%20%E2%82%AC%20rates
   req.getContextPath(): /TEST
```

which to me shows that Tomcat (after setting the URIEncoding attribute) does the right thing (see getPathInfo()), but the path variable is decoded still in ISO-8859-1.

*And the answer is*:

Spring/Rest apparently uses the request encoding, which is a very strange thing to do, as this is about the *body*, not the URI. Sigh.

Adding this:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

fixed the problem. It really should be simpler.

*And actually, it's worse:*

If the method indeed *has* a request body, and that one isn't encoded in UTF-8, the additional forceEncoding parameter is needed. This seems to work, but I'm concerned it will cause more problems later on.

*Another approach*

In the meantime, I found out that it's possible to disable the decoding, my specifying

```
<property name="urlDecode" value="false"/>
```

...in which case the recipient can to the *right thing*; but of course this will make lots of other things harder.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I thing that you need add filter to web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: This sounds good in theory, but doesn't seem to help. Looking at the docs, if enforces the encoding for the *body*, not the URI.

Comment: @Julian: This is a right solution (though `forceEncoding` is not necessary), Spring uses request encoding to resolve path variables, see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UrlPathHelper.html (and you also need this filter for POST parameters anyway).

Comment: @axtavt: oh my, who comes up with designs like this? Anyway, I have been able to confirm that I indeed get UTF-8 when I send an HTTP request with an UTF-8 encoded body, such as POST. I have *not* been able to get the filter working as advertised (I know something is happening because when I break the class name I get a ClassNotFoundException).

Comment: @axtavt: oh, I was missing the filter-mapping element.

Comment: It does not work. Spring MVC 4.0.2 fully annotated. The URLs are decoded in ISO-8859-1 anyway. I had to prepare workaround. A path variable, for example `@PathVariable String var` has to be first decoded using `byte[] bytes = var.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");` and then encoded in UTF-8 with `new String(bytes, "UTF-8");`.

Comment: Tested with Spring MVC 4.3.2. This CharacterEncodingFilter method still works as Spring 3.2.x. It's a pity that Spring uses request encoding to resolve URL, as @axtavt mentioned.

Comment: Had the same issue with Spring 5.0.3 - URLs are still decoded using ISO-8859-1. The @Jagger's solution helped a lot.

Answer (score 4):

The path variable is still decoded in ISO-8859-1 for me, even with the Character Encoding Filter. Here is what I had to do to get around this.  Please let me know if you have any other ideas!

To see the actual UTF-8 decoded characters on the server, you can just do this and take a look at the value (you need to add "HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest" to your controller parameters):

```
String requestURI = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
String decodedURI = URLDecoder.decode(requestURI, "UTF-8");
```

I can then do whatever I want (like get the parameter manually from the decoded URI), now that I have the right decoded data on the server.

Comment: Make sure your dispatch servlet's URL Mapping isn't shorter than the CharacterEncodingFilter, otherwise it won't even hit the filter.

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try to configure connector on Tomcat in server.xml.
Add `useBodyEncodingForURI="true"` or `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` to your Connector tag.
For example:

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Answer (score 1):

But doesn't it suck that you have to mess with the Tomcat configuration (URIEncoding) at all to make this work? If the servlet API provided a way to obtain the path and request parameters in their undecoded representation, the application (or Spring) could deal with the decoding entirely on its own. And apparently, `HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo` and `HttpServletRequest#getQueryString` would even provide this, but for the latter this would mean that Spring would have to parse and decode the query string itself and not rely on `HttpServletRequest#getParameter` and friends. Apparently they don't do this, which means you can't have `@RequestParam` or `@PathVariable` capture anything other than us-ascii strings safely without relying on the servlet container's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had this problem when I tryed to use a word in Portuguese.
The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40821146/10739006) of Avseiytsev Dmitriy  in SpringBoot can be reached with:

**server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8**

in **application.properties** file

I have tested and this Works.

If you are using TDD in your application and using MockMvc to test a **GET** for example, do this way:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/categories/" + NAME2)
                    .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", equalTo(NAME2)));
```

The NAME2 variable is a String: *José*

Comment: the default `server.tomcat.uri-encoding` is `UTF-8`

Comment: When I tried to use the function without set it specifically this way it does not work. Only after set it this way it worked. I don't know why. And the test was the same...only when I writed the encoding part worked