# where and how to decode @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, rest, url

Client sends on the server (implementation doesn't matter):

```
/path/items/ + urlencode(id, SOME_ENCODING)
```

Consider result URL will be:

```
/path/items/my%2Fkey
```

Hence I have on server:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path/items/{identifier}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Item get(@PathVariable String identifier) {
try {
    return DAO.getItemByIdentifier(URLDecoder.decode(identifier, SOME_ENCODING))
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
...
}
```

Is there any way to do it in Spring internally? I mean get **identifier** already decoded, so I could just:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path/items/{identifier}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Item get(@PathVariable String identifier) {
return DAO.getitemByidentifier(identifier); // already decoded!
    }
```

Comment: It is done automatically. When I send a request to `/my%20key`, I get `my key` in the path variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your URIEncoding in tomcat connector in server.xml.

Take a look at: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html

//edit:

you can also try to set up encoding filter in web.xml (or java class) like in:
[Spring/Rest @PathVariable character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470787/spring-rest-pathvariable-character-encoding)

Comment: Also, I need my junit tests to be passed. And they aren't including Tomcat - only MockMvc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Spring's `CharacterEncodingFilter` class in your `web.xml` as a filter as follows:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```