# URL Encoding in spring web application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, url-encoding

I have a spring project which has a lot of get methods. I need to encode the URL parameters. it's an ongoing project so I can't make many changes. I am using tomcat 8. I have already tried the following:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

```
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

And other changes, but none of them work.

Is there any effective and simple way to make it possible?

Comment: i am not using spring boot

Comment: FilterRegistrationBean class not found

Comment: Can you check in the pom.xml file properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring/Rest @PathVariable character encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470787/spring-rest-pathvariable-character-encoding)

Comment: grammar, formatting, spelling. Remove unnecessary text.

Comment: The character encoding should be the first filter on the filter chain if you have multiple filters.